# Groupby 2 different columns Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Dog', '2017', 100], ['Dog', '2017' ,500],['Dog', '2016' ,200],['Dog', '2016' ,150],['Cat', '2017' ,50],['Cat', '2017' ,100],
['Cat', '2016' ,50]], columns=('Pet','Year','Amount'))
```

DF1

```
Pet  Year  Amount
Dog  2017  100
Dog  2017  500
Dog  2016  200
Dog  2016  150
Cat  2017  50
Cat  2017  100
Cat  2016  50
```

I would like to turn the above dataframe into the following:

DF2

```
Pet Year Amount
Dog 2017 600
Dog 2016 350
Cat 2017 150
Cat 2016 50
```

This is grouping by Pet and by Year and summing the amount between them.

Any ideas?

Comment: and you can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with parameters `as_index=False` for not return `MultiIndex` and `sort=False` for avoid sorting:

```
print (df1.groupby(['Pet','Year'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum())
   Pet  Year  Amount
0  Dog  2017     600
1  Dog  2016     350
2  Cat  2017     150
3  Cat  2016      50
```